# Extracting varbinary from database in .NET causes IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have the following situation, I am trying to restore some tables in the databases (SQL Server) which were accidentally deleted (along with the backup). I re-created a table where one of the columns is `varbinary(MAX)` (it might have been something else). When I am trying to extract the data in .NET using the lines of code below I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on the line in the loop:

```
Dim resultReader As SqlDataReader = myComm.ExecuteReader
    Dim previewBytes As Byte() = Nothing
    While resultReader.Read()
        previewBytes = DirectCast(resultReader.Item("preview"), Byte())
    End While
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix that?

EDIT: for a little clarity, here is what the code would look like in C#:

```
SqlDataReader resultReader = myComm.ExecuteReader;
    byte[] previewBytes = null;
    while (resultReader.Read()) {
        previewBytes = (byte[])resultReader.Item("preview");
}
```

Comment: Try GetBytes  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, that won't compile in C#, but this method works for other applications I have (example also in C#):

```
byte[] previewBytes = (byte[])resultReader["preview"];
```